# Getting unexpected time offset from Moment.js toISOString

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetime-format, iso8601

I'm trying to get the standardized [ISO 8601 date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string [from Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/), but I'm not getting the result I expect.

Moment's `toISOString()` method is giving me an output with a 17-hour offset, instead of midnight:

```js
var mom = moment("23-11-2016 00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
alert(mom.toISOString());
// result: 2016-11-22T17:00:00.000Z
```

Why the result is *not* `2016-11-23T00:00:00.000Z`? How I can get that format?

Comment: Because by default moment parses and displays in local time, while [`.toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/) always returns a timestamp in UTC. You probably have -7 hours offset from UTC. Use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) if you want to display date in local time. If your input string represents a UTC time, then use [`moment.utc(String, String);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the [doc says](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.

while [`.toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/) always returns a timestamp in UTC:

> Note that `.toISOString()` always returns a timestamp in UTC, even if the moment in question is in local mode. This is done to provide consistency with the specification for native JavaScript Date `.toISOString()`, as outlined in [the ES2015 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring).

You probably have -7 hours offset from UTC.

Use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) if you want to display date in local time.

If your input string represents a UTC time, then use [`moment.utc(String, String);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)