# momentJS chaining setter .year().day() returns a wrong date

Tags: set, momentjs, chaining

I would like to know with MomentJS why this DON'T WORK :

```
const date = moment().set({
  year: 2019,
  month: 11,
  day: 25,
  hours: 11,
  minutes: 52
});

// or
const date = moment()
  .year(2019),
  .month(11),
  .day(25),
  .hours(11),
  .minutes(52);
// returns 2020-01-09T10:52:26.289Z
```

I need to use this structure and not this one (that is wokring) :

```
moment("2019-11-25T11:52");
```

I think it's a timezone thing but I don't get it ...

Stack blitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/moment-js-kg1kz3

Comment: From [`.toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/) docs: _Note that `.toISOString()` returns a timestamp in UTC, even if the moment in question is in local mode_. Your code is fine, you simply have to use [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to display moment object value.

Comment: @VincenzoC ohhh my god yes ! I’m so dumb I used to use this function... thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MomentJS toISOString result is different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803599/momentjs-toisostring-result-is-different)

Comment: I've pointed out a possible duplicate of your question, you're not dumb, it's a fairly common mistake.

Comment: @VincenzoC yeah it is not really a duplicate since my issue is that moment() create a date with locale timezone. But when I create à moment with an iso string I did not specified the timezone