# MomentJS changing time when doing formatting

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Posted below is my actual code. You can try it yourself. Why is it that momentjs changes the actual value of the time passed? If so, how can I fix this?

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

const startTime = '2020-02-14T06:00:00.000+08:00';
console.log('startTime: ', startTime);
const formattedDate = moment(moment(startTime).toISOString(true)).format('ddd, MMM D, hA');
console.log('formattedDate: ', formattedDate);
```

output:

> startTime:  2020-02-14T06:00:00.000+08:00
>
> formattedDate:  Thu, Feb 13, 10PM

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803599/momentjs-toisostring-result-is-different/40855188#40855188) doesnt answer my question as it suggets to use `.format()` when putting `.tz()` fixes my problem.

Comment: Moment uses the local timezone, `toISOString()` returns UTC

Comment: @BrettGregson even if I remove the `toISOString()`, it still converts it to a different time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MomentJS toISOString result is different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803599/momentjs-toisostring-result-is-different)

Comment: You need to state the desired timezone of the output, like this: `const formattedDate = moment(startTime).tz("Asia/Shanghai").format('ddd, MMM D, hA');`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/kmhdubqa/

Comment: It seems like putting my own timezone fixes it. However what is the best practice if I have to handle multiple timezones?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking; depending on the local time you want to output, state the timezone accordingly each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a timezone issue.

Here's what happens on my console, without moment:

```
> new Date("2020-02-14T06:00:00.000+08:00")
Date Thu Feb 13 2020 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

There's no change of value, it's different representations of the same value.

A good practice is to keep your data in UTC and display it in the user's timezone.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40855188/735964)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use moment timezone to resolve this
`moment.tz(startTime, Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone).format('ddd, MMM D, hA');`